# Переключиться на ветку в удаленном репозитории (remote repo)

Tags: git

Находясь в одном репозитории, необходимо добавить изменения в ветку в другой репозиторий (`git merge` и `git push`.).

Делаю так

```
git remote add repo2 ssh://git@gitlab.name.com:22123/name-project/repo2.git

git fetch

git checkout -b branch2 repo2/branch2
```

Результат:

```
fatal: 'repo2/branch2' is not a commit and a branch 'branch2' cannot be created from it
```

Как добавить изменения в ветку в удаленном репозитории?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> git fetch
> ```

по умолчанию команда `fetch` скачивает объекты и ссылки из хранилища, на которое ссылается текущая ветка.

вам надо получить объекты (и ссылки) либо из всех добавленных хранилищ:

```
$ git fetch --all
```

либо только из хранилища, указанного явно:

```
$ git fetch repo2
```

либо даже только объекты, доступные по явно указанной ссылке из явно указанного хранилища:

```
$ git fetch repo2 branch2
```